# Search results wont paginate

Tags: search

Im trying to add pagination to my Search results page. Each time i do a search for a product that has a lot of results they are all appearing on the one page. Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="container btm_pg_padding">
    <div class="twelve columns margin-top">
        <header>
            <p>{exp:search:total_results} Result(s) for "{exp:search:keywords}"</p>
        </header> 
        {exp:search:search_results results="10" paginate="bottom"}

            <h2><a href="{page_url}">{title} - <span class="channel_name">({channel})</span></a></h2>

            {sn:global_pagination}
        {/exp:search:search_results}
        {sn:global_sidebar}
```

Answer (score 1):

The results parameter needs to go on your [search form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#results), not the [results](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#search-results-tag).